# Python RSA Private Key signing error

Tags: python, rsa, digital-signature

I want to sign a signature using rsa private key and encode it with sha-256
but im always having this error

```
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
private_key = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(open('private.pem', 'rb').read())
signature = rsa.sign(sign, private_key, 'SHA-256')
```

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Encoding to "utf-8" should work for you.

```
private_key = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(open('private_key.pem', 'rb').read())
signature = rsa.sign(sign.encode("utf-8"), private_key, 'SHA-256')
```